# Как проверить наличие класса в jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, условия, проверка

Здравствуйте, как я могу проверить есть ли класс у какого-либо блока с помощью jquery?

Пробовал вот так, но не работает

```
if ($('.menu-on')) {
            $(".burgers__item").click(function () {
                     $(this).removeClass("menu-on");
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".burgers__item").click(function () {
                     $(this).addClass("menu-on");
                    });
                }
                    $('.burgers').click(function () {
                     $('.menu .menu__wrap').slideToggle();
                    });
```

Comment: `hasClass`? https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: `if ($("#block").hasClass("menu-on"))`

Comment: @Regent Благодарю

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Функция .hasClass(), простой пример, выводит сообщение о наличии класса test1 у элемента при клике:

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('test1')){
    alert('У этого блока есть класс test1');
    }else{
      alert('У этого блока нет класса test1');
    }
});
```

```css
.test1{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  background: red;
  }
  .test2{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  background: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test1"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
```